# fetch specific column from sql database and saving value in variable in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

Hi all i am trying to get data of a specific column from my database and then use that data to subtract.. but i am getting an error that `input string is not in a correct format.`

I have tried almost every thing that i know but nothing is working can any one help me??

my code -

```
    string t_qty = "";

    SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("select QTY from STOCK_ARRIVE where BARCODE = @barcode", d.con);
     cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@barcode", txt_barcode.Text);
    d.con.Open();
    SqlDataReader dr = cmd1.ExecuteReader();


    while (dr.Read())
    {
        t_qty = dr["QTY"].ToString();

    }


        d.con.Close();

        try
        {

            int less = 0;
            less = int.Parse(t_qty) - int.Parse(txt_qty.Text);

            SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("update STOCK_ARRIVE set QTY=@pq where BARCODE=@barcode AND S_VC=@vc", d.con);
            cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pq", less);

            cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@barcode", txt_barcode.Text);
            cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@vc", txt_vc.Text);
            d.con.Open();
            cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
            d.con.Close();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write(ex);
        }


        Response.Write("<script>alert('Data has been saved')</script>");
```

Comment: Please check both `t_qty` and `txt_qty.Text`, probably there's something which is not convertible to integer.

Comment: What is the data type of the column `QTY` in the database Is it `int`? Why are you using a string to store it? Also what is the data type for `STOCK_ARRIVE `?

Comment: STOCK_ARRIVE is the name of table from which QTY is coming and yes datatype of QTY is int in database.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably your cnversion `int.Parse(t_qty)` is failing. Instead try using `TryParse()` like

```
int.TryParse(t_qty, out int quanrtity)
```

Comment: @barcode is not getting the value from txt_barcode.text.